# qx.ui.form.Spinner.setValue() question

Tags: qooxdoo

I got a qx.ui.form.Spinner object and I am setting the initial value from an XML file. The value is unfortunately returned as a string, which leads to the following confusing error in Firebug:

```
Error in property value of class qx.ui.form.Spinner in method setValue with incoming value '3': Is invalid!
```

Running this sample in the Playground doesn't produce any error, but the spinner is not being set:

```
// Create a button
var button1 = new qx.ui.form.Button("First Button", "icon/22/apps/internet-web-browser.png");

// Document is the application root
var doc = this.getRoot();

var spinner = new qx.ui.form.Spinner(1, 1, 60);

doc.add(spinner);

// Add button to document at fixed coordinates
doc.add(button1,
{
  left : 100,
  top  : 50
});

// Add an event listener
button1.addListener("execute", function(e) {
  spinner.setValue("3");
});
```

So my questions are:

- should the string value be working? So far it seemed to be seldom a problem when number are actually string.
- should the Playground give an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- No, the string value will not work. Try using the parseInt() function to convert the string into an integer.
- Actually the Playground is giving a problem, but the exception is not handled by the Playground, Try adding a try .. catch and you will see the exact same errormessage you already know.

  try {
        spinner.setValue("3");
     } catch (e) {
        alert(e); 
     }

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.
I already uses parseInt() to get it worked and I submitted a bug report: http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4457

Answer (score 0):

I daresay the Playground should at least log the error in its "Log" window. You might want to consider opening a bug for this.